# I am needing a basic explanation of drools

Tags: drools

I can find lot's of tutorials of drools but they mostly seem to center on the mechanics of what assets, packages, etc are in drools. I have what I think is a very basic question and possibly misunderstanding...

Can someone please help me understand how drools works?

**Is it client/server?**
My application (client) sends data to a drool server. The drool server uses the most up to date rules to process this data into a "solution" and returns the solution as a result to the client.

**Or is it compiled?**
Rules are edited and compiled in drools. The compiled result is imported in a java app as a jar. Every time the rules change the app needs to be recompiled and deployed to make the rules effective.

Or is it something else altogether?

What I am really looking for is the client/server model above.

Answer (score 2):

For the client/server model, look into **drools-camel**, which is a module of droolsjbpm-integration that sets up a REST/SOAP service to apply drools rules.

**Yes, it's compiled**: the DRL gets compiled to Java bytecode (normally during runtime but you can pre-compile it). Since 5.5 the Java bytecode also benefits from JIT hotspot compilation.

Comment: Hmmm...thanks for clearing that up. More specifics. In my case I am running a business process using Activiti on a Tomcat server. I am guessing that JIT may not be an option here? I know less than nothing about JIT...one thing at a time. I think I will look into the drools-camel module and see what happens!